# SSRS 2016 Browser ReportViewer - Relocate View report button

Tags: reporting-services

I have been researching it a lot. Still couldn't find an answer. Does anyone know how to relocate  View Report button on the SSRS 2016 report viewer when report is run in the Browser?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to move the "View Report" button ?

it is inside the parameter box and should have no effect on viewing the report itself.

Comment: I tell you why. I need to add Back button that would take a user back to the main application after viewing a report. I am viewing a report in the iFrame and can place a button there using absolute positioning. But when I resize the Browser it's not looking good. I was thinking to move View Report button a bit lower and place my button on a top of it. It will look perfectly when resizing the Browser.

Comment: Why not just add a reportviewer to the application itself ?
this would allow you to have more control and allow you to add your back button.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Any sample?

Comment: You can find the control on nuget "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms" try and use the 2014 preview version (closest you get to SSRS2016 and is stable)

Comment: Using the combonation of The reportviewer AND ReportingServices2010 You can identify ALL the reports at whatever location they are located on the server and switch between them using the viewer :)

Comment: I recently created giant Reportviewing project and a wrapper project used to deploy reports/datasources/Subscriptions/folders to SSRS using ReleaseManagement(which i cant share as it is owned by the company i work at)

Comment: I have similar  to your "giant Reportviewing project" project too. However, I am showing my reports in the Browser. Can I still use Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms? I am not sure what you mean by "combonation of The reportviewer AND ReportingServices2010".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156043/discussion-between-bernard-walters-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ReportViewerWebForm.aspx as a basis, then yes you can move the button somewhat.

As an example, when your report is wider than the screen area, the View button will be pushed off-screen to the left.

One remedy for this would be to add this style to the abovementioned aspx page:

```
#ParameterTable_ReportViewer1_ctl08 tr:first-child td:first-child
    {

        width : 1% !important;
    }
```